Highchart Sankey Diagram: How to shift node label outside of node?
I have a use case in Sankey diagram where there will only be two levels at any time.
refer this js fiddle link -
https://jsfiddle.net/saurabh_netomi/92xcLuta/15/
tooltip: {
    nodeFormatter:              
}

I want to shift the name of the nodes outside not overlapping with path connecting two nodes.
Refer this image
Sample Sankey Diagram
Please help me out with this
I tried dataLabels property but it's not working

If you set nodes.datalabels.useHTML to true, you can use nodes.datalabels.format to style the elements appropriately so that they are shifted and aligned. However, in order for them to have enough space, you must set the left and right margins of the chart appropriately (chart.marginLeft, chart.marginRight).
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mar9fkgs/ 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes.dataLabels.format 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes.dataLabels.useHTML 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft
